# How to make self.view clickable when using MBProgressHUD?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, mbprogresshud

I am using MBProgressHUD for displaying some messages in iphone app.

Message dimensions are around 200x20 and I set auto hide after 1 second. The problem is that in that 1 second self.view is not clickable.

How can I set self.view to be clickable above and under that message in self.view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MBProgressHUD` functions by displaying the hud as a modal overlay:

> The MBProgressHUD window spans over the entire space given to it by
>   the initWithFrame constructor and catches all user input on this
>   region, thereby preventing the user operations on components below the
>   view. The HUD itself is drawn centered as a rounded semi-transparent
>   view witch resizes depending on the user specified content.

See: http://orfoundation.github.com/ORFoundation/Classes/MBProgressHUD.html

I've found `ZAActivityBar` to be a good alternative to `MBProgressHUD` as it doesn't intercept taps to the view. See the [GitHub page](https://github.com/zacaltman/ZAActivityBar) for more information.

Comment: So there is no any hack? :(